# sql server group by week, get first day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query that will show how much of each item/unit combination each customer ordered each week (group by week) while showing the first day the week. So far I have this but it's not showing the date for monday pf each week

```
select o.customer_name, 
convert(varchar, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0, min(o.delivery_date)), 0), 101) as first_day_of_week, 
item_code, 
(select i.[desc] from items i where i.item = oi.item_code) as description,
unit,
(SUM(oi.price) / SUM(oi.qty) ) as unit_price, 
SUM(oi.qty) as total_qty, 
SUM(oi.price) as total_charged 
from order_items oi inner join orders o on localID = local_order_id where o.[status] = 'submitted' and qty > 0
group by DATEPART(ww, delivery_date), customer_name, item_code, unit
order by customer_name, first_day_of_week, item_code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql

```
select o.customer_name, 

dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, o.delivery_date), 0) as first_day_of_week,
item_code, 
(select i.[desc] from items i where i.item = oi.item_code) as description,
unit,
(SUM(oi.price) / SUM(oi.qty) ) as unit_price, 
SUM(oi.qty) as total_qty, 
SUM(oi.price) as total_charged 
from order_items oi inner join orders o on localID = local_order_id where o.[status] = 'submitted' and qty > 0
group by dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, o.delivery_date), 0), customer_name, item_code, unit

order by customer_name, first_day_of_week, item_code
```